# Why is column name in dataframe have symbols next to it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I am reading in a csv but when I take a closer look at the column names there is a weird symbol next to the first column name, can anyone help me get rid of  this symbol?

How column names look now(not sure what the symbols next to 'year' mean:

```
['ï»¿year', 'sch', 'city', 'prop_id']
```

How I want column name to look:

```
['year', 'sch', 'city', 'prop_id']
```

my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

path = ('file_path')

cameron_county = pd.read_table(path + '/2016_GCC_prelim_appraisal_info_20160630.txt',
                             encoding = 'latin1',error_bad_lines = False)

print(cameron_county.head(1))
print(cameron_county.columns)
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks like unciode BOM
try

```
cameron_county = pd.read_table(path + '/2016_GCC_prelim_appraisal_info_20160630.txt',
                             encoding = 'utf-8',error_bad_lines = False)
```

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding

`ï»¿` is the CP1252 representation of the utf-8 BOM hex code: `EF BB BF`

Answer (score 2):

A post import solution might look like:

```
columns = pd.Index(['ï»¿year', 'sch', 'city', 'prop_id'])
columns.str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]', '')

Index([u'year', u'sch', u'city', u'prop_id'], dtype='object')
```